# How to send websocket upgrade headers via php client

Tags: php, http, websocket, http-status-code-400, handshake

I'm trying to upgrade my php client to use websockets, however, I receive the error: `400 Bad Request` when sending the headers. (my ws server is in node.js)

the message is output in `$buf` because that's what the servers sends back... (I think)

I'v minified the code so it's easy to read, my real code has multiple error checks thoughout ;)

full error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 11
```

client

```php
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$port = 8000;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($sock, $host, $port));

$headers = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Key: i9riAfOgSsKwUlmLjIkGA==\r\n\r\n";

socket_write($sock, $headers, strlen($headers));
socket_recv($sock, $buf, 2045, MSG_WAITALL);
echo $buf;
```

simple server

```js
import WebSocket from "ws";
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8000 });
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    console.log("connection recieved!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably "Host:....\r\n" and "Origin:...\r\n" are requiered in the $Headers